# How to Calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have this code:

```
Private Sub CalculateBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateBUT.Click
    If SelectTheDateComboBox.Text = "Calculate the difference between two dates" Then
        FromYearTextBox.Text = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Year
        FromMonthTextBox.Text = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Month
        FromDayTextBox.Text = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Day
        ToYearTextBox.Text = ToDateTimePicker.Value.Year
        ToMonthTextBox.Text = ToDateTimePicker.Value.Month
        ToDayTextBox.Text = ToDateTimePicker.Value.Day
        Dim DaysMyString, MonthsMyString, YearsMyString As String
        Dim DaysDifferance, MonthsDifferance, YearsDifferance As Long
        DaysMyString = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Day
        MonthsMyString = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Month
        YearsMyString = FromDateTimePicker.Value.Year
        DaysDifferance = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, ToDateTimePicker.Value.Day, CDate(DaysMyString))
        MonthsDifferance = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, ToDateTimePicker.Value.Month, CDate(MonthsMyString))
        YearsDifferance = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, ToDateTimePicker.Value.Year, CDate(YearsMyString))
        DifferenceTextBox2.Text = DaysDifferance & "Days, " & MonthsDifferance & "Months, " & YearsDifferance & "Years"
End Sub
```

and my problem  in the picture below :
[image]

so, i need some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want DateDiff to give you the number of days between two dates and you want DaysDifference to hold the result, and that's fine:

```
DaysDifferance = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, x, y)
```

But for this to work x and y need to be dates.

When you take `ToDateTimePicker.Value` (which is a date) and add `.Day` on the end it's no longer date.

So you want:

```
 DaysDifferance = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, ToDateTimePicker.Value, CDate(DaysMyString))
```